# Base class parameter in a derived class' method

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Here is my code:

```cpp
class Base
{
    virtual shared_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
};
class A : public Base
{
public:
    A(const string &str) {
    _str = str;
    }
    shared_ptr<Base> clone() const
    {
        return make_shared<A>(*this);
    }
private:
    string _str;
};

class B : public Base 
{
public:
    B() { }
    B &AddToStorage(const string &key, Base &&val)
    {
        //_storage[key] = val; ?
        //_storage[key] = val.clone(); ?
        return *this;
    }
    shared_ptr<Base> clone() const
    {
        return make_shared<B>(*this);
    }
private:
    map<string, shared_ptr<Base>> _storage;
};
```

Notice the class B and it's method AddToStorage. How can I call this function with both class A and B? As in:

```cpp
B test;
test.AddToStorage("a", A("test1"));
test.AddToStorage("b", A("test2"));
test.AddToStorage("c", B());
```

And how can I later differentiate between class A and class B when I access _storage (map)?

EDIT: I've tried to implement cloning, but failed - https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/08/make-polymorphic-copy-modern-cpp/ followed this tutorial, but there seems to be an error "no matching function for call to 'A::A(const B&)'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I call this function with both class A and B?

Both `std::shared_ptr<A>` and `std::shared_ptr<B>` are convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, which is what your function expects, so providing a shared pointer will work.

```
test.AddToStorage("a", std::make_shared<A>("test1"));
test.AddToStorage("b", std::make_shared<A>("test2"));
test.AddToStorage("c", std::make_shared<B>());
```

> And how can I later differentiate between class A and class B when I access _storage (map)?

In order to differentiate them, you would need to have a virtual function in `Base`, and (ideally) override it in `A` and `B` to do different things. Having a class hierarchy managed with pointers with no virtual functions at all is rather dubious, so you probably should have at least one.

Comment: Having a virtual destructor would suffice (and should usually be used for any kind of polymorphic hierarchy). As for differentiating, virtual methods is preferable, but one can alternatively use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), or in the case of `shared_ptr`, [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

Answer (score -1):

To add to the other answer. If you compile your code:

```
test.AddToStorage("c", B());
```

the errors is pretty helpful:

```
no viable conversion from 'B' to 'std::shared_ptr<Base>'
```

What you're passing in is an actual *object* of `B` and not a *pointer to* B. Now one could try changing that to

```
test.AddToStorage("c", new B());
```

But that wouldn't compile too since the constructor for `shared_ptr` here

[image: SHARED PTR CONSTRUCTOR]

is marked *explicit*. So the only way out is to do something like

```
test.AddToStorage("c", std::make_shared<B>());
```

As for detecting the types, as the other answer suggests, having a virtual inheritance hierarchy would be a good idea. If you have RTTI enabled (which is usually enabled by default), you could also use something like [type_index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) which is a wrapper over the runtime `type_info` and can be used to index into containers.

```
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::string> type_names;
type_names[std::type_index(typeid(A))] = "A";
```

and then later from a

```
shared_ptr<A> pA;
std::cout<<type_names[std::type_index(typeid(*pA))]<<'\n';
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but is there a way that I could change only the method (not the second snippet)? I've heard about clone patterns but couldn't get them to work..

Comment: @Ventuaer to preserve the second snippet as-is, the method would have to take `Base&&` instead of `shared_ptr<Base>`, but to actually store the `val` object in the `map` correctly, you would need to implement cloning. If you are having trouble with that, then you need to edit your question to show what you have tried that is not working for you.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau had to edit it unfortunately :(

Comment: @Ventuaer FYI, `const Base &val` would have worked, too. But either way, `_storage[key] = val.clone();` will work just fine. The real problem is that your `clone()` methods are trying to invoke copy constructors that you simply have not implement. Also, the code shown does not match the error message you claim to be getting, as there is no `A` object being constructed from a `B` object.